# primefaces datatable not working properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

im developing webapps using jsf and primefaces and im facing one problem in retrieving data in datatable i.e., displaying datas in the xhtml page using datatable tag of primefaces

here is my xhtml code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<h:form id="form">  
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10"> 
<h:outputText value="Batch Name" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{allot.batchName}">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Batch" itemValue="" />  
                <f:selectItems value="#{allot.batchList}" />  
                <p:ajax listener="#{allot.handleBatch}" />  
            </p:selectOneMenu> 
            <p:dataTable var="batch" value="#{allot.batchInfoList}" >  
                <p:column headerText="Tan">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{batch.tan}" />  
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>  
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>  
</body> 
</html>
```

here is my action bean used for retrieving the data

```
package com.cation.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.cation.bean.BatchInfo;
import com.cation.controller.CationController;

public class Allocation {

    private String batchName;

    private List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList;

    private List<String> batchList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private CationController cationController = new CationController();

    public String getBatchName() {
        return batchName;
    }

    public void setBatchName(String batchName) {
        this.batchName = batchName;
    }

    public List<BatchInfo> getBatchInfoList() {
        return batchInfoList;
    }

    public void setBatchInfoList(List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList) {
        this.batchInfoList = batchInfoList;
    }

    public List<String> getBatchList() {
        return batchList;
    }

    public void setBatchList(List<String> batchList) {
        this.batchList = batchList;
    }

    public Allocation() {
        try {
            batchList = cationController.getAllBatch();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String handleBatch() {
        try {
            batchInfoList = new ArrayList<BatchInfo>();
            batchInfoList = cationController.getBatchByName(batchName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "allotInput";
    }
}
```

my condition is that when selecting a value from the selectone menu tag i'm getting the selected value and by using the value to retrieve some list of objects and display in the xhtml page using datatable. But the problem is i'm getting list of objects in action, but no datas shown in the xhtml page.

can anyone help me to solve this issue plz.

Comment: How do you fill `batchInfoList` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use "submit" buttons in this case.

1. You select an item from your menu
2. You click on a submit button
3. Table is being filled with Data.

What you will need also is an id for your dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" ...
```

And in your Button you need to update the Table:

```
<p:commandButton value="Update my table" actionListener="#{allot.handleBatch}" update="table" ...
```